# Вопрос про переменные

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот у меня post запрос

```
 data={action :'random'};
        $.post('core.php', data, function(response){
            obj= JSON.parse(response);
            $.each(obj, function(key,value){
            var id = value['id'];
   });
        });
```

Как мне переменную id использовать дальше ( за скобками )?
Например для:

```
 $('#guest').click(function(){
        $(location).attr('href', 'profile.php?id='+id);
    });
```

Если описать еще более подробно, то есть страница, где выводится рандомный юзер( вся информация о нем ) на странице также есть 2 кнопки, отправить сообщение и зайти в гости. Так вот, в момент загрузки страницы, я уже имею id юзера. Осталось правильно использовать id чтобы заработали кнопки )) Как то так.

Comment: вынести определение `id` вне функции, либо передать её в какую то функцию как входной параметр... зависит что вы там в цикле делаете

Comment: Объявите ее извне скобокк))

Comment: мое твое не понимать ) Может то что я хочу, так не работает?

Comment: Опишите задачу полнее.

Comment: переменная id в данном случае получает значение value['id'], которое приходит с базы, дальше как я указал в примере, хочу с помощью get передать дальше, но передать id нужно в момент нажатия кнопки на сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях был дан правильный ответ, определить переменную id  вне post-запроса.

Ваш код должен принять вид:

```
var id;
data={action :'random'};
    $.post('core.php', data, function(response){
        obj= JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(obj, function(key,value){
        id = value['id'];
 });
});
```

Данные останутся в id даже после выхода из post-запроса и код ниже сработает.

```
$('#guest').click(function(){
    $(location).attr('href', 'profile.php?id='+id);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам) я вот понял только на примере!